# Can I use dictionary for calling same function but different parameters?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to call function by storing in dictionary.
Actually, I will collect

```
dictStar = {1:...,2:..., ... , 100:....}
```

but I try only 3 first

```
star = [1,2,3]

dictStar = {                    #######################
        1: drawStar(2,1,s),     #    Problem Here     #
        2: drawStar(2,4,s),     #    They always      #
        3: drawStar(2,7,s)      #    call 3 functions #
}                               #######################

def drawStar(row,column,s):
    global plaRotate
    plaRotate = plaRotate+0.5
    sm2 = buildScaleMatrix(s/10,s/10,s/10)
    column = (column - 5.5)*s
    row = -(row - 1.0)*s
    glUniform1i(fragMode, int(7)) 
    Obj_platonic.draw(programID_1,projectionMatrix,np.dot(buildMoveMatrix(column,20,row),np.dot(buildRotateMatrix(0,1,0,plaRotate),sm2)))
    glUniform1i(fragMode, int(4)) 

def dstar():                            ####################
    if len(star) > 0:                   #    When I call   #
        for i in range(len(star)):      #                  #
            dictStar(star[i])           ####################

def removeStar(x):
    global star
    if x in star:
        star.remove(x)
    else:
        print("No starID: ",x)

def main():
    dstar()
```

just I call dictStar( anything )
they will call all function in dictStar
So, I try

```
def: dictStar(x)
return
{                    
        1: drawStar(2,1,s),     
        2: drawStar(2,4,s),     
        3: drawStar(2,7,s)     
}
```

But It happen the same thing like above T_T
I avoid if-function because It will spend a lot of time I guess
in C++ I will write

```
switch(x)
    case 1:
        drawStar(2,1,s);
    case 2:
        drawStar(2,4,s);
    case 3:
        drawStar(2,7,s);
```

I believe in C++ write this It works well but I have to write in Python
If I ask a common question, I am sorry I really don't know how to write on Python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Storing functions inside a dictionary

Functions are first-class objects in Python and so you can store them inside a dictionary. For example, if `foo` and `bar` are functions, and `my_dict` is a dictionary, you can store the functions inside the dictionary in the following manner:

```
my_dict = {'foo': foo, 'bar': bar}
```

Note that the values are `foo` and `bar` which are the function objects, and NOT `foo()` and `bar()` which are function calls.

To call `foo`, you can just do `my_dict['foo']()`

---

### Storing functions with default parameters

Make use of [`functools.partial()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

`partial()` returns a new function that behaves just like the old one, but with any arguments you passed in, already filled. Following is an eg. of how `partial` works:

```
>>> import functools
>>> print_with_hello = functools.partial(print, "Hello")
>>> print_with_hello("World")
Hello World
>>> print_with_hello()
Hello
```

---

### Solution to your problem:

In your case, `dictStar` would be defined in the following manner:

```
dictStar = {
    1: functools.partial(drawStar, 2, 1),
    2: functools.partial(drawStar, 2, 4),
    3: functools.partial(drawStar, 2, 7)
}
```

Now, you can call the dictionary like `dictStar.get(1)(s)` or `dictStar[1](s)`

Working eg:

```
>>> import functools
>>> def drawStar(row,column,s):
...     print """row: %s, column: %s, s: %s """ % (row,column,s)
... 
>>> dictStar = {
...     1: functools.partial(drawStar, 2, 1),
...     2: functools.partial(drawStar, 2, 4),
...     3: functools.partial(drawStar, 2, 7)
... }
>>> 
>>> s=10
>>> dictStar.get(1)(s)
row: 2, column: 1, s: 10 
>>> dictStar[1](s)
row: 2, column: 1, s: 10 
>>> dictStar[2](s)
row: 2, column: 4, s: 10 
>>> dictStar[3](s)
row: 2, column: 7, s: 10 
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks guy. I will try this method